# Use "Community" to award bounties to long unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request, bounty, community-user

The Community user should place small bounties (maybe around 10 points) to questions that are unanswered. At the moment the community-user does the following in response to old unanswered questions:

- Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention

Giving a small bounty would incentive people to answer old questions so there is not a influx of old answered questions on the site.

For example, consider this question - *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829378/how-much-memory-is-used-by-a-css-class*.

I asked this question a year ago. At the moment it does not give anything to the site as all. It says that I had a problem a year ago when trying to write a data dictionary. Also, if this question had not been linked to this question it probably would not get any more views and will go unanswered forever.

Applying a bounty would cause people to look at the question and sort it out. This means when a user stumbles upon the question when they have a similar issue, the question is not just an answered question from a year ago.

To look at the question in a different light which question deserves more appreciation answer a question that has just been asked or providing a answer to a question that has been unsolved for a considerably long time. I would say the second as the user has had to wait for the problem (where they probably would of unsuccessfully tried to find a solution) you have sorted it out for them this is why badges such as [revival](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/126/revival) exist.

Comment: Personally, I despise seeing old unanswered questions float to the top of the front page. Usually they're unanswered for a reason. The system already incentivizes answering old questions, with its rep system combined with question-bumping and even the *Excavator* badge. I think that's enough.

Comment: The questions need have community answer or need moderator action if they are unanswered for a reason but just leaving them in a the state they are is not helpful for anyone

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238018/automatic-system-generated-bounties-on-old-highly-upvoted-unanswered-questions etc

Comment: `just leaving them in a the state they are is not helpful for anyone` maybe - but an automated bounty placed on every unanswered question with no regard to its quality is just going to attract a lot of bad answers from people hunting for the bounty. With 12+ million questions, we may have to live with an underbelly of abandoned questions. And you never know, sometimes an old unanswered question finds a great answer one day.

Answer (score 10):

No.

If you found good and useful old unanswered question - provide bounty yourself.

Otherwise there is no need to bump questions that no one is interested in. Especially to promote spending time on them with extra bounty. There is enough recent questions that need some action that can be done instead.

Comment: The minimum bounty is 50 rep which is to much for a good old unanswered question however if I did do this of even if a found a group of people that were willing to I doubt we would make much of a difference because of the number of old unanswered questions also bad unanswered questions need action to either to reword them or too post a community answer explaining the potential problem and the solutions

Comment: @AlexanderRD Yes, that the whole point - someone need to *care enough* about old question to push it to front page via edit or pay with bounty to call for more attention.

Comment: @AlexanderRD I'm very confused now what you actually trying to achieve - you already have power to act on bad questions irrespective of age (downvote vote/flag to close or edit to improve) with no impact on your reputation. You still have not explained what is expected benefit to force others to look at such old bad or simply not useful questions. (Also don't forget that questions with bounty can't be closed - so you propose to remove important way to deal with bad questions)

Answer (score 3):

The way the bounty system works is:

- User A gives up a portion of their direct reputation on a question in the form of a bounty
- User B answers the question, and from there...

  - User A awards the bounty in full, or
  - The system awards half of the bounty to a question with a score of 2 at the end of the grace period.

Note that in all contexts, the reputation for the bounty **comes from the investor**.  That is, somebody is *losing* reputation for the sake of *gaining* an answer.

This idea wouldn't work because:

- The Community user [has no reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) to award bounties, and
- The idea of the bounty is to incentivize good answers at the cost of reputation.

If the reputation came out of thin air, that would undermine bounties.

Comment: The reputation would only be a small amount and the bounty would come from the investor waiting so it would be user waits 2 months without a answer hence community awards 10 reputation and pokes question the user pays with time not with their reputation

Comment: @AlexanderRD:  You still haven't addressed the fatal flaws with this approach:  **where the reputation actually _comes_ from** and **how this wouldn't undermine the bounty system**.

Comment: I realise it would cause reputation to be in essence created from nothing but I feel it would not undermine the bounty system because bounty question would be more important as you would receive a lot more bounty from them (the minimum bounty is 50 rep which is 10 times more reputation)

Comment: I'm still not convinced that this doesn't undermine the bounty system.  If you want to really try to convince me, you'll need to put your rationale **into your question**.

Comment: so if you want a question answered you put a bounty on it and if the site wants the question answered (stack overflow should not be full of answered questions) then the site will put a much smaller bounty on it

Comment: I have edited the question to include a example stated why action would need to be taken on the question

Comment: @AlexanderRD _"stack overflow should not be full of answered questions_" .... wut?

Comment: The reputation from upvotes doesn't come from anywhere, and downvoting is in no way zero-sum. I don't think the creation of reputation is the problem. On the tags I look at, unanswered questions are largely dross. Very largely. You can't even count on question upvotes distinguishing good from bad, because people upvote questions for... whatever reason they feel like. I'd prefer to see the dross disappear over generating small bounties to allow them to be answered - if they could have been answered, they would have been. It's not a lack of a bounty.

Comment: @BillWoodger:  Upvotes are *not* comparable to bounties.  The system itself *awards* reputation freely because of upvotes.  The system also *removes* reputation per user request because of bounties.  Nothing here has convinced me that the intent of bounties isn't being undermined by allowing them to be generated by thin air.

Comment: Well, I think it's just a bad idea. If concerned about undermining the Bounty system, you could just call it something else. No-one is going to ask a question and wait for a year or more for an answer just to save them doing a real bounty themselves. My concern would be encouraging answers to rubbish questions which should have been closed and deleted, but weren't.

Comment: @BillWoodger:  In all honesty, there's a lot of other issues at play there - notably, why these questions slip through the cracks, and why the system doesn't take care of these.  Addressing that through the bounty system seems counterintuitive at best and has the ability to undermine the entire bounty system.  I don't disagree that there's an issue, but this isn't the way to attack it.

Comment: Meh, the fact that rep is being generated out of thin air isn't even slightly the problem -- after all, the bounty system, at present, routinely throws away large chunks of rep that vanish into nothingness, upvotes and suggested edits grant rep from nowhere, and downvotes cause one *or both* parties to lose rep into an abyss. So the rep economy just doesn't work this way.

Comment: However, the dilution of the featured tab is a very real problem, and I think that's worth stating more clearly and strongly.